# How do I say "Have you spoken to A about B yet?"

Tags: grammar

Quick question, how would I say "Have you spoken with your parents about me staying at your house yet?"

Could it simply be

我问一下，关于我在你们家住几天， 你跟你的家庭说了没 ？

or does 关于  sound too formal？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

你跟父母說了我要在你家留宿的事沒有?

The question above should suffice.

Comment: Could I not say 关于？

Comment: @Stephen 关于 is often used in a more formal conversation.

Comment: @Aldour: Why not "你有沒有告訴父母我會在你家留宿?"

Comment: Because it seems that Stephen wants to ask the question verbally, or in a less formal way. So I gave my opinion, trying to be as "verbal" as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is OK, except that `parents` means `父母`, so you need change `家庭` to `父母`.

And `关于` is necessary in your sentence. Anyway, your sentence is formal as a whole.